# Using PyQt in PyQGIS inside QGIS 3.16

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqt, function

This code Using PyQt5 extracted from http://www.tutorialspoint.com does not work when I add it in a script in the console of QGIS 3.16. Can you enlighten me on this subject?

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui

def window():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    b = QtGui.QLabel(w)
    b.setText("Hello World!")
    w.setGeometry(100,100,200,50)
    b.move(50,20)
    w.setWindowTitle("PyQt")
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
       window()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the original code have a different indentation :

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

def window():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    b = QtWidgets.QLabel(w)
    b.setText("Hello World!")
    w.setGeometry(100,100,200,50)
    b.move(50,20)
    w.setWindowTitle("PyQt")
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window()
```

It's a code to create a widget with a label `Hello World!` inside a <kbd>QApplication</kbd> `app` loop.

But, when you launch QGIS, it's already a Qt application with its own loop. So, the working code will be :

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

def window():
    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    b = QtWidgets.QLabel(w)
    b.setText("Hello World!")
    w.setGeometry(100,100,200,50)
    b.move(50,20)
    w.setWindowTitle("PyQt")
    return w


w = window()
w.show()
```

Comment: Thinks, 
It's OK, but after i shall like to install in this box coordinates (X,Y) and an  EPSG etc... to create a points or lines. Where can I found  examples dealing with this problem. Have you an idea about this.

Comment: I suggest you to start with the official documentation : https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins/plugins.html#writing-a-plugin and to install `Plugin Builder` QGIS plugin to have a plugin with a simple dialog you can modify and improve. After, you have to know Python and how to develop with PyQt.

Comment: Im going to try this. Think you for your help and for your advice.